# Invoking method interceptor using AOP with @annotation in API(interface) method

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-aop

Would like to intercept the method annotated with custom annotation(@TestDocument in this case ) using @annotation in the point-cut expression.

It is working when both interface and implementation method are annotated with custom annotation.(but expecting to work by annotating only the interface method assuming it is possible.please correct,if not so).

Please suggest.

sample code :
Advice class

```
   public class AfterAdvisor  implements AfterReturningAdvice {
   public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method,Object[] args, Object target)  {

          System.out.println("AfterAdvisor : after method invocation!");
```

}

Custom Annotation:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
 public @interface TestDocument {
 string test default "";
  }
```

config details:

```
    <aop:config>
          <aop:pointcut id="addPointcut" expression="@annotation(com.xxx.annotation.TestDocument)" />
          <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="addPointcut" advice-ref="afterAdvisor" order="1" />
   </aop:config>
 <bean id="afterAdvisor"     class="com.xxx.AfterAdvisor" />
```

Testservice and TestServiceImpl are the interface and implementation class respectively having common method addTest(TestVO testVo) as shown

now 2 cases:

1.addTest(TestVO testVo) method is annotated with @TestDocument (test="test")) custom annotation in both interface and implementation class as shown below.In this case it is intercepting the advice class printing "AfterAdvisor : after method invocation!" from AfterAdvisor class above as the point cut expression="@annotation(com.xxx.annotation.TestDocument) is for intercepting any method that is annotated with @TestDocument.

Interface and implementation class(both method are annotated with @TestDocument):

```
  public interface TestService{
   @TestDocument (test="test"))
   public  testVO addTest(TestVO testVo) ;
      }
   public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{
   @TestDocument (test="test"))
    public  testVO addTest(TestVO testVo) {
          //do something
          return testVo;
   }
```

But this below case is not working and expected to work,if possible.

2.addTest(TestVO testVo) method is annotated with @TestDocument (test="test")) custom annotation in interface only shown below(not in implementation class as above,we dont want to annotate the method in the implementation class).
in this case it is not intercepting the advice class therefore not printing "AfterAdvisor : after method invocation!" from AfterAdvisor class above.

Interface and implementation class(only interface method is annotated with @TestDocument):

```
  public interface TestService{
   @TestDocument (test="test"))
   public  testVO addTest(TestVO testVo) ;
      }

   public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService{
    public  testVO addTest(TestVO testVo) {
          //do something
          return testVo;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can be done. In Java annotations are not inherited from interfaces. What could be done would be either to:

1. Change the TestService interface into abstract base class and add @Inhertied to your annotation definition
2. Change your pointcut to be applied to all sublcasses/implementations of TestService: execution(public * com.xxx.TestService+.*(..))

Comment: Hi R4J,

thanks for replying.

May be the question is not clear I think or I couldn't grasp the answer :).
"Change your pointcut to be applied to all sublcasses/implementations of TestDocument: "

TestDocument is the custom annotation class.There is no implementation for this.

Rephrasing /modifying the question above  for more clarity.Please suggest.

Comment: @sam you're right: too much copy/paste. I have edited my answer, it should be more clear now :)

Comment: But found this example in spring doc (not working in our case though)

        expression="execution(* com.xyz.myapp.service.*.*(..)) and
        @annotation(com.xyz.myapp.service.Idempotent)"/>
Idempotent is cutom annotation here.
so that we can restrict based on both package structure and method having specific annotation to intercept specific interceptors.Performance wise also better.
Or Is it  possible only if there is no interface(Testservice)  and implementation(TestServiceImpl) relation exist.As you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Inherited annotation scanning only works on classes, not interfaces.